# Storing the exact memory-image of a vector

Tags: c++, parsing, optimization

In my current application I need to create a case-base repository following
the Instance-Based learning paradigm well-known in the AI community.

The case-base repository needs to be stored persistently between two calls into
the application.

However I am worried that the serialization / de-serialization implied by this
(probably to JSON or a light-weight format for key-value pairs) imposes so much
I/O overhead that programming a good indexing mechanism (which operates on the 
in-memory description of the case-base) will accelerate only a small-part and thus
give no substantial benefit.

Now I think that there are two solutions

a) Try to index directly into the file, performing I/O and indexing at the same
time.

b) Somehow save the memory image of the in-memory representation of the case-base
into the file so that the "file parsing" then reduces to a simple memcpy (including memory-mapping the file). Note that
the file-format is then binary and not UTF-8 based as under a).

Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem and tried something along the
lines of b) ?

Comment: How complicated is your vector? Do you need to share the data between multiple platforms (ie. endianness)?

Comment: Are you sure your current plan to serialize will cause a slow down?  Sounds like premature optimization to me.  I would suggest to get it working first, then if you find that IO is a bottleneck (through actually profiling) then try to find a more optimal solution.

Comment: Agree with Chad - this sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: Hm it might be premature opt -- However just for the sake of doing something funky (maybe not in this application after all). is there a way to do it? There would be a lot of portability issues because we are at the bit-level here, right?

Comment: This depends a lot more on your the type you store in the vector and not the vector itself. If your types are trivial (eligible for `memcpy`) than this should be rather easy. Using memory mapped files will be harder. You need to have a custom allocator for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [memory mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)?